# Difference in arrow notations: straight to the right vs to the right and down

Tags: calculus, limits, notation

I was reading a paper and saw both of these arrow notations in it and was confused what the difference was?

$n\rightarrow 0$ versus $n\searrow0$

I would have thought they mean the same thing but since the paper used both notations I imagine they don't?

Comment: Can someone suggest another tag?  I'm not sure what would be appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second notation means "decreasing to", the first just "going to". In the same way you can use the "increasing to" arrow: $\nearrow$.

Both "increasing to" and "decreasing to" implies "going to" but the vice versa does not hold.

Sometimes $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$ are also used.

Comment: That doesn't sound right… are you saying a two-sided limit does not imply the one-sided limits!?

Comment: @Joffysloffy Nope, I'm not talking about right/left limit. These arrows are "specifications" that say how to sequence (or the function) converge. For example you can say $1/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, but more precisely you can say $1/n \searrow 0$ because it is decreasing to it. In the case of variables, $x \searrow a$ could be a shortcut for $x \to a^+$

Comment: Ooh, I see! Right, so then it clearly doesn't indeed, as a sequence wouldn't both increase and decrease to something! Correct?

Comment: Yeah, you are right

Comment: Okay, great! Thank you for clearing that up!