# What does this notation mean (limes from left/right)?

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, notation

I have never seen this way of writing before, 
we have always written $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}$ for the left side and $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}$ for the right side of limit. Or we have worked with $<,>$.

So what does it mean and does it even exist...? I couldn't even find it in latex which explains why I have used a picture. Very ridiculous if people want make your life harder by always finding new ways of notating something. As if there weren't enough already.

[image]

Comment: For reference: in $\LaTeX$, you are looking for `\nearrow`, `\swarrow`, and possibly `\downarrow`, `\uparrow` for more fun.

Comment: Sorry, it should read `\searrow`, not `\swarrow` above. My comment went south.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x\nearrow 2$ typically means *"$x\to 2$ in an increasing fashion"* (and therefore, in particular it implies $x\to 2^-$).

Similarly, $x\searrow 2$ typically means *"$x\to 2$ in an decreasing fashion"* (and therefore, in particular it implies $x\to 2^+$).

---

*As mentioned in the comments below, the $\nearrow 2$, $\searrow 2$ notations (and their less $LaTeX$-savvy equivalents $\uparrow$/$\downarrow$) make more sense for sequences, where the monotonicity implication they carry is a stronger statement than just writing $\to 0^+$ or $\to 0^-$. For the "real-analysis" (non-sequential) version, they are basically equivalent, so feel free to use the one you (or your peers) like most.*

Comment: See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1543507/difference-in-arrow-notations-straight-to-the-right-vs-to-the-right-and-down) (indeed, as mentioned there sometimes $x\downarrow 2$ and $x\uparrow 2$ are used.)

Comment: Alright thanks a lot!
I'd like to know which notation is the most common one in your opinion pls. What have you used in your university?

Comment: Well, it really means $x \to 2$ **and** $x \le 2$. Similarly for $x \downarrow 2$.

Comment: All of them, depending on the teacher. But as far as I remember, the $\nearrow$/$\swarrow$ were mostly used for sequences, and $x\to2^{+}/2^-$ (one-sided limits) for "regular" (calculus/real analysis) limits. No clear rule, though, just personal preferences.

Comment: @copper.hat No, when writing $x_n \nearrow 0$, there is the additional idea that $(x_n)_n$ is monotone non-decreasing. At least in every case I have seen or used it.

Comment: @ClementC.: With a sequence that makes sense, but the notation that the OP was asking about, $x \downarrow 2$, has no implied notion of monotonicity.

Comment: (Indeed -- but I figured mentioning the other use was definitely a good idea, as this notation makes most sense for sequences, and there it has that stronger meaning.)

Comment: @copper.hat Edited my answer accordingly.